# Changing a Crawl Rule, must I do a full crawl to update the change

Tags: 2013, search, crawl, crawl-rules

I made a crawl rule change that should impact a document library and cause some new documents to be inserted.  However since it's a smallish change, and a full crawl can take awhile on our site (half a day most likely) I'm hoping I can update the library only with those changes somehow.  Forcing a reindex in advanced settings then doing an incremental did not index the documents.  Am I stuck doing a full crawl or is there another way to get those documents in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Crawl Rules have been added, deleted, or modified, a [full crawl is required](https://littletalk.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/when-you-need-full-crawl-in-sharepoint-search/).

Here is the official [technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262926%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: oh well, now go pardon me while I sob here a bit....I'll mark it the answer even if I don't have to like it....

Comment: we are here, trying to tell you what is the correct answer of the question...But liking & disliking, we cant control. :)